# 'Overload resolution ambiguity' with and without 'suspend' lambda in functions

Tags: kotlin, overloading, suspend

Look at this example:

```
fun f(block: suspend () -> Unit) {
    println("with suspend")
}

fun f(block: () -> Unit) {
    println("without suspend")
}

fun main() {
    f(suspend {
    })

    // This call cause compilation error:
    // Error:(16, 5) Kotlin: Overload resolution ambiguity:
    // public fun f(block: () -> Unit): Unit defined in root package in file Main.kt
    // public fun f(block: suspend () -> Unit): Unit defined in root package in file Main.kt
    //
    // f({
    // })

    // This call cause compilation error:
    //
    // Error:(25, 5) Kotlin: Overload resolution ambiguity:
    // public fun f(block: () -> Unit): Unit defined in root package in file Main.kt
    // public fun f(block: suspend () -> Unit): Unit defined in root package in file Main.kt
    //
    // f {
    // }
}
```

Here is declared two functions (one with `suspend` keyword in lambda and one without).

Questions:

1) How to call first or second function? As you can see I can call function with `suspend` but can't call function without `suspend` keyword.

2) It is possible to rewrite `f(suspend {})` with [trailing lambda](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#passing-a-lambda-to-the-last-parameter) (i.e. use something like `f suspend {}`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) You can call the second function with some workarounds. For example,

```
val foo = {}
f(foo)
```

or

```
f({}.also{})
```

or even shorter:

```
f({}!!)
```

will invoke the function with non-suspend parameter. In these cases you declare the lambda out of the context of being a function parameter, so it's not suspendable by default.

2) Trailing lambda syntax does not support explicit `suspend` modifier, so you have to use parentheses to declare that your lambda is suspendable.